# Use scicomp like our collective computational science blog/encyclopaedia!

Tags: discussion

I'd like to call everybody's attention to a [recent Stack Overflow blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/05/encyclopedia-stack-exchange/) by Joel Spolsky, the CEO of the StackExchange Network.  In it, he explicitly encourages a more blog-like approach to using the sites:

> What’s that “Blog” circle supposed to be about, you ask? WHERE’S THE BLOGGING?
>
> Since Stack Overflow launched, we’ve been trying to explain that it’s not just a Q&A platform: it’s also a place where you can publish things that you’ve learned: recipes, FAQs, HOWTOs, walkthroughs, and even bits of product documentation, as long you format it as a question and answer.
>
> As Jeff wrote:
>
> - if you have a question that you already know the answer to
> - if you’d like to document it in public so others (including yourself) can find it later
> - it is OK to ask, and answer, your own question on a relevant Stack Exchange site.

So please, go for it.  If you have any questions, leave an 'answer' or comment on this post or find us in the [scicomp chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1878/computational-science).

Note: I'm breaking the Q&A format because I think it's pretty silly to keep it up in an announcement meta post.

Comment: Don't worry about breaking the Q&A format for announcements. There's precedent for moderator-types to do so. For instance, see a post by Aarthi: [Moderator Pro Tem Announcement](http://meta.scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/96/moderator-pro-tem-announcement)