# Should open questions be closed?

Tags: discussion

So far a decent chunk of the questions I've asked on this site are open in the research sense.  E.g., a question like "does problem X have complexity Y" will result in answers giving the best known algorithms with complexities > Y, while also confirming that no one knows whether Y is possible.

How should such questions be handled?  Should I mark as accepted an answer that I'm confident describes the best known complexity, or leave them open to indicate that no one yet knows?  There are arguments either way: in many cases it's unlikely that the question will be completely closed any time soon, but leaving it open does reflect its actual status.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My feeling is that we should leave these questions open.  We have enough active researchers on this SE that people should feel comfortable with questions that turn out not to have a known answer.  The Community bot will automatically bump these questions up every so often so that new visitors will get a chance to look at them.  It is going to play havoc with your "accept" rate, so you might want to mix in some less challenging questions, or ones that [you have discovered the answer to and would like to share](https://scicomp.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/295/use-scicomp-like-our-collective-computational-science-blog-encyclopaedia).